# how synchronize recv() when multithreading cpp CRT

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, recv

I have a server interacting with multiple clients where the client send messages to the server and the server reads them via recv() method. The problem I getting is that Im using waitforsingleobject(handler, 10000 millisecs) in order to make the server wait for a few seconds to interact with one client and then let others access to it but then I start seeing answer from the server with the wrong message to the client and getting blocked. So looks like a synchronization issue.

So my question is (since I'm a begginer in c++) how could I ensure that every incoming message is received and replied to the right client, allowing all the clients interact with the server.

Comment: use boost asio - async accept

Comment: The old fashion way is using the select() API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're two alternatives.

First is a pretty standard model - one thread per one client. When a client connects, you start a thread to handle it.

Second approach doesn't require many threads. You should use WSARecv() on an overlapped socket instead of recv(). This way, you can simultaneously open multiple receive operations, one per client, and wait them all in a WaitForMultipleObjects(). To be specific, you will wait on event inside WSAOVERLAPPED. Remember that WaitForMultipleObjects() has a limit on number of wait objects. When exceeded, you will need to run another thread. The return code from WaitForMultipleObjects() will tell you which client has sent data, so you can reply to it.

Or, as suggested above, you could probably use select() to figure out which socket has data.